# window.location not providing correct URL

Tags: javascript, php, url-rewriting

I have this `window.history.pushState("", "title", myCtxURLVersion);` chaning the current URL of the page. When I use the below code, it doesn't show the correct URL.

It shows `domain.com/index.php` when the actual browser bar is showing `domain.com/foobar`.

`currURL = window.location;` does not give me this. Nor does: `currURL = document.URL;`

How would I go about doing this and then getting it into a `js` variable. I'm happy to accept PHP answers if that fixes the issue.

I should mention that earlier in the script I use this: `window.history.pushState("", "title", myCtxURLVersion);`  myCtxURLVersion is the new URL.

Thank you!

Comment: is it providing the original url in js variable. that seems highly unlikely as js has nothing to do with htaccess.

Comment: The browser URL bar is showing the correct URL that I want to be stored in the js variable. If I refresh the page again, the correct URL shows up. Otherwise it shows `domain.com/index.php` instead of `domain.com/asdf`

Comment: btw.. `window.location` returns a `Location` object and not just a URL string.

Comment: According to [http://caniuse.com/#search=history](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) the session history management has some missing support and known issues. Which browser do you use?

Comment: are u forwarding user to another page in your script ? a live example could work

Answer (score 5):

Using pure Javascript your option would be
    window.location.href

However, I will guess that you will employ some Javascript library at some point, so you might want to search for that question there.

Also, your redirection doesn't affect your Javascripts.

Javascripts are client side, redirection is server side.

Comment: `window.location.href` doesnt fix it.  The browser URL bar is showing the correct URL that I want to be stored in the js variable. If I refresh the page again, the correct URL shows up. Otherwise it shows domain.com/index.php instead of `domain.com/asdf`

Comment: Eh... You have to enter "domain.com/asdf" into the URL, it will then be redirected via .htaccess mod_rewrite rules to /index.php, and since your redirecting rule has QSA pass all variables along. If you enter domain.com/index.php you will get that url in Javascript.

Comment: Also, check if you really need RewriteBase here. Usually for CI your RewriteBase is "/".

Comment: Oops sorry I'm confusing myself, the `.htaccess` is for a seperate part of the functionality. My bad. I just want a way to get the current URL that is shown the browser. (Note my edit to the original post about the history.pushState)

Comment: Read here a little bit more about window.histor.pushstate then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history.

    var currentState = history.state;

That is what you need to find current url after pushstate function.

Comment: its giving me `null` when I use `history.state`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current url using javascript use `window.location.href`

```
var curreURL = window.location.href;
```

Comment: I have edited the original question, I do a `window.history.pushState` to change the URL in the address bar. But then when I go to get the current URL, it doesn't appear properly.

Comment: you mean once you get redirected to a new url, you want to go back to the previous url.

Comment: I just want to get the current URL that can visibly seen the browser. I don't care about backwards and forwards history.

Answer (score 1):

you must use JavaScript variable like this `var curreURL = window.location+"";` and it will perfectly work
try it

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add "/#" (http://domain.com/#/mon-url) before your URI or the page will get reloaded and your JavaScript program will initiate, also correct me if I am wrong, are you trying to write a browser history manager ? If so, there is a pretty good library for that https://github.com/browserstate/history.js check it out.
Cheers